Applescript requires me to "grant access" to a downloaded file
I know that downloaded files are marked as "suspicious" or something (ls -l shows and '@').  My question is how to get around this in AppleScript.  Here's my situation:
I download a file from Yahoo Finance.  Here's the ls -l output:
-rw-r--r--@ 1 gidi  staff    782 Oct 15 17:44 portfolio.csv
If I double-click this file, or do open portfolio.csv in a shell, it opens in Excel without any hassles.   However, if I run an AppleScript that does:
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open "/Users/myusername/Desktop/portfolio.csv"
end tell

Then I get a popup that asks me to "grant acess" to the file (see below).
I also noticed that if I first open the file, close Excel, and then run the AppleScript, then it opens the file without the popup.  So presumably somewhere in the OS it has been noted that the file should be accessible (even though the ls -l listing still has an '@').
So... is there an AppleScript command to say explicitly that I am granting access to the file?  Or, should I say somewhere that AppleScript itself has access to all files?
Thanks!


Pretty much all sandboxed apps these days add a com.apple.quarantine extended attribute (the '@') to stuff from the internet, which restricts their usage until permission is given.  Once you (not a script) have used the file, the quarantine attribute is modified, and a somewhat stickier com.apple.macl extended attribute (kind of a whitelist) may also be added to allow a user and application access.  These are all parts of the security system of current versions of the OS.
AppleScript doesn't have anything to manipulate files, but you can remove the extended attribute with the xattr shell command, for example:
do shell script "/usr/bin/xattr -d com.apple.quarantine " & quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file)


Excellent!  Thank you!
